# verify method was called with array, with clear failure message

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I have a method I verify as part of my test. One of its parameters is an array that can potentially be very large (over 100 bytes).  How can I easily find the point of failure, without needing to go through some serious debugging?

The tested line is:

```
mockDependeny.verify(x=>x.callMethod(expectedModel, expectedModel.Length, It.IsAny<otherKindOfParam>()));
```

`expectedModel` is passed in the method (a theory) and is an array.

One set of data/expected in the theory works, but the next one says that it failed. The message it gives me is not very helpful -

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x=>x.callMethod([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...], 175 , It.IsAny())

> Perfomed invocations:
> Mock(x): MyDependency.callMethod([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...], 175 , instanceOfOtherParam)

All I can glean from this is that somewhere in the next n-10 items in the array, there is something that does not match up ( the first ten items are the same, the overall length is the same)

Is there a way to get better feedback from the test, so I do not have to debug and manually compare the contents of the expceted vs actual arrays?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test? What does that show?

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mre] for us to be able to say what's wrong.

Comment: @Xerillio I can debug the test, but then I would need to compare really long arrays manually. The point of this question is to find out how to avoid that

Comment: Comparing two "datasets" should be fairly trivial. For a low-level example: print out the array and use a [tool to compare strings](https://text-compare.com/). Alternatively it would be nice to see a [mre]. Otherwise there's no way of telling what's wrong.

Comment: My issue is not finding what is wrong with the test. I know how to do that. I am just looking to see if there is a more efficient way, or if there is a way to get clearer feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `expectedModel` array parameter with an `It.Is<>` and implement anything you want. E.g.:

```cs
mockDependency.Verify(x => x.callMethod(It.Is<byte[]>(m => VerifyThisEnumerableParam(m, expectedModel)), expectedModel.Length, It.IsAny<object>()));

...

private bool VerifyThisEnumerableParam<T>(IEnumerable<T> received, IEnumerable<T> expected)
{
    if (received != expected)
    {
        var receivedArray = received.ToArray();
        var expectedArray = expected.ToArray();

        if (receivedArray.Length != expectedArray.Length ||
            receivedArray.Where((t, idx) => !Object.Equals(t, expectedArray[idx])).Any())
        {
            // now let's visualize the two thing
            throw new AssertFailedException($@"received != expected
expected: {String.Join(", ", expected.Select(t=>t.ToString()))}
received: {String.Join(", ", received.Select(t => t.ToString()))}");
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above isn't fool proof (no additional null, etc. checks), but hope you got the idea. If you prefer just the first differing index or something else just implement it in the method.